# `visible: false` statement doesn't work on Windows but it works on Linux

Tags: qt, qml

On Qt 5.11.2, I have a QML item like this:

```
Menu {
    MenuItem {
        visible: false // Works on Linux, however doesn't work on Windows!!!
        enabled: true
        text: qsTr("First menu item") + emptyString
        onTriggered: doSomething()
    }
}
```

I couldn't figure out why the `visible: false` statement works on Linux but **not** on Windows. I mean, on Linux, the menu item is actually non-visible, but on Windows the menu item is visible, as if the `visible: false` statement is ignored on Windows. Can anybody help?

### UPDATE 0

As suggested by @teh_raab I used `Component.onCompleted` in the code. Surprisingly, the qml logs `qml: Visible:  false` however, the menu-item is still visible on Windows:

```
    MenuItem {
        visible: false
        Component.onCompleted: {
            this.visible = false;
            console.log("Visible: ", visible); // logs `qml: Visible:  false`
                                             // But menu item is still visible!!!
        }
        enabled: true
        text: qsTr("First menu item") + emptyString
        onTriggered: doSomething()
    }
```

### UPDATE 1

Problem finally gets solved with the following code which is **very strange**:

```
    MenuItem {
        visible: true // When this is set `true`, the menu item gets hidden on Windows!!!
        Component.onCompleted: {
            this.visible = false; // Now this statement actually works!!!
            console.log("Visible: ", visible); // logs `qml: Visible:  false`

        }
        enabled: true
        text: qsTr("First menu item") + emptyString
        onTriggered: doSomething()
    }
```

Comment: I have not seen this myself. Is it still showing if you set the visibility to false in MenuItem -> Component.onCompleted?

Comment: @teh_raab Thanks! That's a great idea. Unfortunately I don't have access to my computer right now. I'll try it as soon as possible 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not seen this myself. Is it still showing if you set the visibility to false in MenuItem -> Component.onCompleted?